# Simulating Multple Entries and Exits in a Vehicle Car Park in Java with Multi Threading

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, simulation

I have currently created classes such as CarPark, and Floor to represent the car park. I have used an ArrayList of the Floor class to show multiple levels in the car park.

I want to have multiple entries and exits on different floors, equipped with elevators to get from floor to floor.

How should I approach this? I want to be able to add and delete multiple vehicles to the car park when the vehicle enters and leaves at the same time.

How can I use threads and locks in this case?

============== Structure ============

```
public class CarPark{

private ArrayList<Floor> floorList;
private ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicleList;

}
```

Methods Implemented:

- getFloorList() : ArrayList
- getVehicleList(): ArrayList

- getMostSuitableFloorForVehicle(Vehicle): Floor

- addVehicle(Vehicle): void
- getFreeSlots(): double
- deleteVehicle(String): Vehicle
- getVehiclePercentages(): HashMap<String, Double>
- getOldestVehicle(): Vehicle
- getLatestVehicle(): Vehicle
- getVehicleById(String): Vehicle
- getVehicleByDayYear(String, String): ArrayList

  ```
    public class Floor implements Comparable<Floor>{

    private double maxCapacity;
    private double currentCapacity;
    private int currentNumberOfVehicles;
    private ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicleList;
    private ArrayList<VehicleTypes> preferredVehicleType;
    private ArrayList<VehicleTypes> possibleVehicleType;
  ```

  }

Methods Implemented:

- getCurrentNumberOfVehicles(): int
- getCurrentCapacity(): double
- getVehicleList(): ArrayList
- getPreferredVehicleType(): ArrayList
- getPossibleVehicleType(): ArrayList
- getAvailableNumberOfSlots(): double
- isParkingSlotsSufficient(Vehicle): boolean
- addVehicle(Vehicle vehicle): void
- getVehicleById(String): Vehicle
- deleteVehicleByInstance(Vehicle): Vehicle
- deleteVehicleByPlateId(String): Vehicle
- toString(): String
- compareTo(Floor): int

Rest are just vehicle classes that will be added to the car park.

Comment: I added an overview, code is just long to put

Comment: Please kindly note that Stack Overflow is a Q/A platform where you show your concrete code and describe what you tried and how the actual result differs from your expectations or ask other concrete questions. It is **not** a platform where others do your entire job or homework assignment for you for free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following mre uses two threads to simulate cars entering and cars leaving. You can control the rate by changing the `SLEEP` time:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CarPark {

    private static final int NUM_OF_FLOOORS = 4, SLEEP = 3000;
    private final List<Floor> floorList;

    public CarPark() {
        floorList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
        for(int i=0; i < NUM_OF_FLOOORS; i++){
            floorList.add(new Floor(i));
        }
    }

    private Floor getRandomFloor() {
        Collections.shuffle(floorList);
        return floorList.get(0);
    }

    void simulateRandomTraffic(){
        simulateRandomEntries();
        simulateRandomExits();
    }

    void simulateRandomEntries(){
        new Thread(()->{
            while(true){
                getRandomFloor().addVehicle(new Vehicle());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(SLEEP);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    void simulateRandomExits(){
        new Thread(()->{
            while(true){
                getRandomFloor().removeRandomVehicle();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(SLEEP);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CarPark().simulateRandomTraffic();
    }
}

class Floor{

    private final double maxCapacity = 100;
    private final List<Vehicle> vehicleList;
    private final int floorNumber;

    public Floor(int floorNumber) {
        this.floorNumber = floorNumber;
        vehicleList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public int getCurrentNumberOfVehicles() {
        return vehicleList.size();
    }

    public boolean isFull(){
        return maxCapacity <= getCurrentNumberOfVehicles();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return  getCurrentNumberOfVehicles() <= 0;
    }

    public int getFloorNumber() {
        return floorNumber;
    }

    private Vehicle getRandomVehicle() {
        Collections.shuffle(vehicleList);
        return vehicleList.get(0);
    }

    public boolean removeRandomVehicle(){
        if(isEmpty()) {
            System.err.println("Floor "+ getFloorNumber()+" is empty. Can't remove vehicle");
            return false;
        }
        return removeVehicle(getRandomVehicle());
    }

    public boolean addVehicle(Vehicle v){
        if(isFull()) {
            System.err.println("Floor "+ getFloorNumber()+" is full. Can't add vehicle");
            return false;
        }
        vehicleList.add(v);
        System.out.println("Floor "+ getFloorNumber()+" vehicle added ("+ getCurrentNumberOfVehicles()+"/"+maxCapacity+")");
        return true;
    }

    public boolean removeVehicle(Vehicle v){
        if(isEmpty()) {
            System.err.println("Floor "+ getFloorNumber()+" is empty. Can't remove vehicle");
            return false;
        }
        vehicleList.remove(v);
        System.out.println("Floor "+ getFloorNumber()+" vehicle removed ("+ getCurrentNumberOfVehicles()+"/"+maxCapacity+")");
        return true;
    }
}

class Vehicle{}
```

The next enhancement is a car park `Queue`.
Have a third thread push cars into the `Queue` (or multiple queses, one for each entrance, all filled by the same thread). 
Have `simulateRandomEntries()` pull from the queue (or queues) and push to a random floor.

Comment: Wow! this is a good approach... I have only one small thing to ask, after that this will be the perfect answer. Now let's say for example we have 6 entries and 6 exits in the car park.  Shall I use a thread pool and run simulateRandomEntries() 6 times to mimic the multiple entries. And use a synchronized list in the car park to keep track of the vehicle IDs and then also run simulateRandomExits() 6 times to mimic the 6 exits in the system?

I will also so try and use the Queue which is very practical.

Comment: Also just make sure of one more thing, will making each method synchronized provide any advantage here? Is it necessary to use that wherever I modify the synchronized list?

Comment: See my edit: I would use one thread for each task: one for pushing vehicles into entrance queues, one for pushing vehicles to the floors, and one for pushing vehicles out to a random exit.

Comment: Side note: are you planning to visualize the car-park simulation?  If so which tools are you planning to use (swing ? JavaFX ?)

Comment: You used synchronized list but you forgot to synchronize() them. Otherwise they are not threadsafe (unless that is the intent in the question).

Comment: @S.S.Prabhu thank you for your comment. I do not think `synchronize()` is needed for accesses: "..._synchronizedCollection() method. As the name suggests, it returns a thread-safe collection backed up by the specified Collection_". AFAIK it is needed only for iterating: "_if we want to iterate over a synchronized collection and prevent unexpected results, we should explicitly provide our own thread-safe implementation of the loop"_ ([source](https://www.baeldung.com/java-synchronized-collections))

Comment: @c0der if I am to use JavaFX to visualize, should there be any changes that should be made?

Comment: Built correctly a model (which basically contains data and logic) should work with any view. Having said that JavaFx has some nice mechanisms and features (like ObservableList, Binding) which I find very convenient for such simulation. See an example here: https://bitbucket.org/c0derepo/shop-floor-simulator/src/master/

Answer (score 1):

The basis of any simulation, or game, is a [game loop](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-runnable-example/).  This is a loop that runs for a certain period of time.

In Java, you can use a [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) added to a [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) to run a simulation loop.

Here's an example `Runnable`.

```
public class SimulationRunnable implements Runnable {
    
    /** Simulation run time, in minutes */
    private final int duration;
    
    private final Random random;
    
    private final SimulationView view;
    
    private final SimulationModel model;
    
    public SimulationRunnable(SimulationView view, SimulationModel model, 
            int duration) {
        this.view = view;
        this.model = model;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.random = new Random();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int iterations = duration * 60 * 5;
        
        for (int index = 0; index < iterations; index++) {
            // Update simulation model
            
            // We will add cars for the first 10 hours (minutes)
            
            if (index < iterations - 600) {
                for (int jndex = 0; jndex < 5; jndex++) {
                    if (random.nextInt(10) == 5) {
                        // Add car
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // We will remove cars for the last 10 hours (minutee)
            
            if (index > 600) {
                for (int jndex = 0; jndex < 5; jndex++) {
                    if (random.nextInt(10) == 3) {
                        // Remove car
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // Report status every 300 iterations
            if (index % 300 == 0) {
                
            }
            
            // Pause simulation loop
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

To start the simulation, you create a `Thread` using the `Runnable`.

```
new Thread(new SimulationRunnable(view, model, 12)).start();
```

Let's assume you want to simulate a 12 hour period where cars enter and leave the parking lot.  One possible simulation could be:

- Cars enter the parking lot for the first two hours.
- Cars enter and leave the parking lot for the next eight hours.
- Cars leave the parking lot for the last two hours.

Let's also assume that the simulation timer runs as one minute representing one hour.  So the simulation will run for 12 minutes.

Let's also assume that the simulation loop runs five times a second.  That means the simulation loop will execute once every 200 milliseconds, for a total of 3,600 executions.

Now all you have to do is decide how many cars enter the parking lot per hour and how many cars leave the parking lot per hour.  The rates should be pretty close to one another.

Too many cars entering the parking lot per hour will fill the lot.

Too few cars entering the parking lot per hour will leave the lot mostly empty.

The game loop will update your simulation model.  Every so often, say every game hour (minute) you report the status of your parking lot.

Comment: So how can I add multiple vehicles at once to the car park. Shouldn't I opt for an approach that uses a concurrent loop for that? If I want to add multiple items to several array lists, how can Implement that here?

Comment: @L_Jay:  The "Update simulation model" comment is where you add vehicles as well as remove vehicles.  I'd suggest adding and removing vehicles at random so the time between adding vehicles isn't constant but you can still predict the number of vehicles added over a period of time.  You avoid a lot of concurrency issues with one master game loop.

Comment: When I start the thread, does this add multiple cars at once, since it is a normal for loop? Also when adding the multiple cars, should I use a lock to lock the floor object when adding a vehicle?

Comment: @L_Jay: Let's do the math.  You attempt to create 5 cars every 200 milliseconds.  However, because of the `Random`, you only have a 10% (1 in 10) chance of creating a car.  So, on average, you create 1/2 a car every 200 milliseconds, or 2 1/2 cars a second (minute).  The same math applies to the remove car loop.  You can adjust the loop limits and/or the probability of creating/removing a car.  I'd keep the math the same for both the car creation loop and the car removal loop.  No locks are needed anywhere in your code.

Comment: I get the math, it makes total sense. But I want to use threading and concurrency, That's my main intention here. I want some pointers with that please....

Comment: @L_Jay: You have to use threading.  You don't have to use concurrency.  If you want to make your project super complicated for no apparent reason, go right ahead.  Don't expect any additional help.